# What is the appropriate analysis test to show differences in a part of the sample?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova

in my experiment I have 3 Pretests: PreA, PreB and PreC done at the same day; also I have 3 PostTests: PostA, PostB and PostC done 3 weeks later.
During the 3 weeks between pre tests and the posts tests there was a training  followed by 40 participants. The control group was 33 participants. Group: Trained (n=40) or Control (n=33).

To analyse data, I divided the sample in three levels (low, middle, upper) according to the performance in preA and PreB, I called it the ABLevel.

These are the results for the Percent Change (improvement) in test C (analysed in R): [anova and t.test only for low level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tRGK.png)

**There is a big difference between Control and Trained in the Low level. If I run a t.test only for low level, it is significant the different between control and trained groups. But it is not correct to run a t.test only of a part, isn't?**

If I run a t.test of the whole sample, it is not significant the difference between gropus *control vs trained):
[t.test and also a lm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Andr1.png)

Please, is there another type of analysis more appropriate to show better the difference between control and trained groups for the low level profile?
Thank you very much!

Comment: So you didn't use the data from the `C` test, pre or post? And it sounds as though you combined the results from tests `A` and `B` and in the lower quantiles (`low level`) there was a difference between the trained and control groups. Is this right? Can you provide a glimpse of what the data looks like?

Comment: Thanks Antoni. I use the data from Tests C (PreC and PostC) as a independent variable to calculate the improvement after the training. I calculate the percent correct of test C like this: PCh= [(PostC- PreC) / PreC]*100.  Test A and B are used to dived the sample in three categories: low, middle and upper. The original idea was to use also test A & B to see the improvement after the training but there is not any improvement in A & B tests, only in test C. I don't know if it is correct to use a t.test for each category with PCh of test C as independent variable  comparing control vs trained.

Comment: Nuria, First off, welcome to the site. It's a great place to learn statistics and probability. There are a lot of participants with great mathematical knowledge. But to get people interested in solving a problem it is a good technique to show some of your data - typically it can be truncated, or changed in a way that it has only your question as the common denominator with your actual data. Otherwise, it is difficult to get a clear idea of what you are doing, and the chances of getting a response go down.

Comment: You seem to be choosing your tests based on the data, which (as you already seem concerned about) is a problem. If you expected before seeing the data that the low, medium and high on pretest would perform differently, you could make a model for that and test for differences in each. But if those groupings are based on subdividing observations after you see them, that's a bad idea for a couple of reasons; if you expect the treatment effect to be related to the pre-test level it sounds like you should be using a regression model.

Comment: Some additional clarification on (i) what you wanted to know beforehand  (what the primary questions of interest were), and (ii) exactly what you did (e.g. *why* did you think to subdivide on pretest, and *how*, exactly you did it) -- would help.

Comment: Thank you Antoni, I will take into account your advice. It was just that I can only have two links and no images in my questions because I am new, so I couldn't put more data. In the two links I wrote in my question there are some results of the data.

Comment: Thank you Glen, I suspected that a training could have different effect depending on the previous level of knowledge but I didn't knoe exactly in what direction (i.e. better for low level or for upper level?). The levels were calculated considering the number of correct answers in the pre test: Which observation delimints the lower 33% of the data
quantile(RightPre, 0.33) for the low level.
Which observations are between the 33.33% and 66.66% of the data
quantile(RightPre, c(0.3333,0.6666)) for the middle level and observations bigger 66.66% of the data for upper level.

Comment: I suppose my main problem is that the training was not effective enough and I try desperately to find some significant improvement between post and pretest (in percent change or in Zscore) analysing the data in all possible ways...

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not have divided the data. Categorizing continuous variables is almost always a bad idea.

Second, since you have each person measured multiple times, the errors are not independent. There are various ways to deal with this, but one is to use multilevel models.

Third, if you are concerned that people with different starting scores will make different progress, you can look at an interaction of initial score and time.